# android: asynctask

Tags: android, class, static, android-asynctask

I got a question concerning AsyncTasks:

In my project I have multiple AsyncTask classes like CustomTask1 and CustomTask2, etc., in those I'm doing some HTTPPOSTS and parsing stuff.
As a parameter for the AsyncTasks I got some final static Strings like (http://IP/"some special commands for a Webinterface").

Actually, I don't want 4-5 AsyncTask classes, 'cause many things in there are actually the same, so I wrote the same code multiple times.
Wouldn't it be better to code one single AsyncTask and put some methods in there and define static values, that decide which method use? The problem then would be that I also need different return values from the AsyncTask, sometimes a String, sometimes an ArrayList, how to do that?

the whole thing would be a bit tidier

thank you

Comment: and how we supposed to help you without any snippet of Code ?

Comment: I didn't mean to get some code of you, but to get some idea of how I could "clean up" my project

Comment: you should add your code in order to help you with the best approach to clean your code

Answer (score 1):

You write:

> I don't want 4-5 AsyncTask classes, 'cause many things in there are actually the same, so I wrote the same code multiple times...

That's the problem, - dont write same code multiple times, but DO HAVE multiple AsyncTasks. AsyncTasks should be used just as a Facade for your code for every particular task type containing **TASK-SPECIFIC logic only**. Of course if those tasks share the same "algorithm pieces" then write these algorithm parts in one place and just expose it differently through typed tasks. I'd do something like:

```
class TaskLogicImpl //contains various task general static methods like parsing string etc...
{
   static void preParseServerResponse().......
}
```

then create tasks:

```
class Task1 : AsyncTask<URL, Integer, List>
{
  call your. TaskLogicImpl....
}
```

Because every task is typed, you will be able to return different values in a type-safe way

Comment: yea, I know what you mean. thank you very much!
those classes really share the same "algorithm pieces", so I was jus' wondering if it would be better to have less code in terms of "Source Code Style"

Answer (score 0):

If you have some methods which are repeated in you application consider to write a class which extends the Application class. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, mobile url pasting is not fun :)